# Is masking a sql param always safe when with two single quotes escaping

Tags: sql, oracle11g, escaping

Is it safe in an `Oracle 11g` database to mask a parameter when I replace a single quote with 2 in a `SQL` string? (`' => ''`)

Something like that:

sql = "select * from user where name='" + input.replace("'", "''") + "'";

Comment: Question is not clear at all. Please share some sample data and an example what are you doing ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is! Touch wood, or we're all screwed. Here's the [fullest explanation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)) I've seen on SQL masking. Clearly, it's ids and the like that are vulnerable, because they're not enclosed. But, for goodness sake, use parameters. Don't construct your SQL like that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about injections but... Someone may use absence of bind variables to slow down your DB by filling Shared pool with almost identical single-use statements, forcing hard parsing etc.